# which port I use when I want to connect remix to my local quorum network?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, quorum, network, rpc

I want to deploy a smart contract on my local network. I executed a local node via

```
   PRIVATE_CONFIG=ignore nohup geth --datadir ./Node1/new- 
   node-1 
   --nodiscover --verbosity 5 --networkid 31337 --raft -- 
   raftport 51001 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 22101 -- 
   rpcapi 
   admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3, 
   quorum,raft --emitcheckpoints --port 21101 2>>node1.log &
```

I have to use localhost:\127.0.0.1:21101 or 22101? I want to know the difference betwwen the two ports and what are used for?

An other question if you don't mind: When i use the port 21101, it fails to connect and when I consult the node log I find :

```
    Failed RLPx handshake addr=[::1]:42552  conn=inbound    
    err="read tcp [::1]:21102->[::1]:42552:  i/o timeout"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remix, like most of Ethereum wrappers access node via RPC API. To connect remix, you would tell it to connect on port 22101 as this is what you define to be your rpc port. The only other caveat is that you may need to add `--rpccorsdomain` flag as well to your set up.

We have a number of helpful presentations that would help you here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=17CAe2A0-2k-4UWMAuLF5fIwPxIbWt12d -- in particular, take a look at the using public tools with quorum.

Comment: thank you very muc, it was about --rpccorsdomain .
Do you know what the port 21101 is used for?

Comment: Yes, the `--port` defines the DEVP2P layer networking -- this is the API that other nodes use to connect to your node and share info such as txns and blocks